# GitHub Webhook to Jenkins Multibranch pipeline building every branch rather than just the one with pushed commit

Tags: github, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

The behaviour of our Jenkins server appears to have changed recently, and now builds triggered by GitHub webhook appear to be triggering all branches, rather than just the branch with the new commit.

For each repository we have branches for each environment release - `main`, `stage` and `live` Commits pushed to each branch auto-deploys to its appropriate environment via a webhook from GitHub to our Jenkins server.

However now if a commit is pushed to `main`, the multibranch pipeline is building all three branches.

To complicate things a little further, our repositories all use a shared library that contains the pipeline. Let me share an example;

1. `Jenkinsfile` in each project repository

```
buildAndUploadToS3('config.json', 5)
```

`config.json` is just a small json file where we store parameters for each build (environment name, slack channel for notifications etc, and the second parameter (5) is just the number of builds we want Jenkins to retain.

2. `buildAndUploadToS3` in the shared library

```
def call(String configFilename, Number retainedBuilds = 3) {

  pipeline {
    
    triggers {
      githubPush()
    }

    agent any

    options {
      disableConcurrentBuilds()
      buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepString: "${retainedBuilds}", artifactNumToKeepStr: "${retainedBuilds}"))
    }

    stages {
      stage('Build step would be here, but deleted for succinctness') {
        steps {
          script {
            ...
          }
        }
    }


  }

}
```

My suspicion is that this is caused by the way that the repo-based pipeline is calling the shared library, but I'm not sure on the best way to change the syntax. I've tried wrapping the `buildAndUploadToS3` call in the Jenkinsfiles as a pipeline of its own, and moving the `githubPush` call there, but that throws an error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the way to tackle this correctly? Is there, for example, a way I can access the branch name from the webhook and then just wrap the call to `buildAndUploadToS3` in a check of that name?

For clarity, I do want each branch to build when a commit is pushed to it - I just don't want them all to build any time a commit is pushed to any one of them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the connection between the pipelines (repos) and your jenkins shared library, but if it is actually chained (interconnected) than you might be probably facing the same issues as here: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10904/jenkins-trigger-build-if-shared-library-changes (if you have it enabled in configuration)?